# $f: [a, b] \mapsto [a,b]$, $f$ is monotonically increasing $\Rightarrow \exists~ x \in (a, b)$ such that $x = f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, monotone-functions

I can prove this, if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, using $g(x) = f(x) - x$. But can't figure out, how can I prove it, if $f(x)$ is only monotonically increasing.

Comment: @bof Or it’s just some sloppy shorthand, like people would write on a blackboard in a hurry.

Comment: @k.stm yes, you are right. It was just a sloppy writing

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X = \{x ∈ [a..b];~f(x) ≥ x\}$. Now $X ≠ ∅$, as $a ∈ X$, so you may consider $ξ = \sup X$.

- Generally, $f(X) ⊆ X$, as for $x ∈ X$, by monoticity $f(x) ≥ x \implies f(f(x)) ≥ f(x)$.
- You have $f(ξ) ≥ f(x) ≥ x$ for all $x ∈ X$ by monoticity of $f$, so $f(ξ) ≥ \sup X = ξ$.
- But then $ξ ∈ X$, so …

Comment: By the way, you should really just draw a sketch and start reasoning along it.